# CSS Grid Make Columns Fill Right to Left

Tags: html, css

I need to invert the direction of which side the grid items start filling from. In other words, I need to fill a CSS grid with boxes from right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the grid container, apply the following CSS

```css
.container {
  // display: grid;
  direction: rtl;
}

.child {
  direction: ltr; // turn the direction back to default as it is inherited from parent direction
}
```